# Getting mean curvature using the normal vector map $N(x,y,3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, computer-vision

To be honest, it is a question for computer vision.

There is a normal vector map $N(x,y,3)$ represents the normal vector $(nx,ny,nz)$ on the point $P(x,y)$. If the resolution is high enough (2448x2048), can we get the approximate mean curvature by this normal vector map?

I found a proof about the relationship between normal vector and curvature,
it says 
$$\operatorname{div} (N)=\kappa_1+\kappa_2,$$
where $\kappa_1, \kappa_2$ are the principle curvatures. See [here](http://willson.cm.utexas.edu/Research/Sub_Files/Surface_Phenomena/Spring%202000/surface_normal_proof.pdf). It is easy to get the part of $x$ and $y$, but not $z$ since there is no $z$ coordinate.

Comment: Is this a question about mathematics?

Comment: ya,it is about how to get the mean curvature